# How to convert xHr y min to minutes in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I update time in minutes and sometime xHr y min format. I use javascript pasted below

```js
function EXCEED(time) {
  if (time<45)
    return ' ';
  if (time === "w/o")
    return ' ';
  if (time === "Leave")
    return ' ';
  else
    return time-45;
}
```

This works only if time is in minutes I want this to work even if time is eg. 1Hr 45min---It has to convert 1Hr 45min to 105 min and return without showing any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

using split and regex makes it quite simple :

```
function EXCEED(time) {
  if(time.toString().indexOf('Hr')>-1){ // check condition to have valid hours
    var hrs = Number(time.toString().split('Hr')[0].replace(/ /g,''));//extract hour
    var min = Number(time.toString().split('Hr')[1].replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));//extract minutes
    var total = 60*hrs+min;// do the math
    Logger.log(hrs+'*60 + '+min+'  = '+total); // just to check
    return total;//return result
  }
  if (time<45)
    return ' ';
  if (time === "w/o")
    return ' ';
  if (time === "Leave")
    return ' ';
  else
    return time-45;
}
```